# What does it mean when it says a git step is "1 ahead"

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to learn git by playing around with it using SourceTree as as tool.

I added my local repository to a BitBucket repository and then made a couple of changes locally. I committed them, and then pushed them.
I then logged onto BitBucket and manually changed a portion of the document (item "Added 4").
Then I went back to my local copy and changed it again and committed it. When I tried to push it, it told me I first had to pull and merge. So I did.

Then I pushed again. It worked.

Now, the master (the top one. Why are there two?) carries a caption saying `2 ahead`. What does this mean exactly? What is it ahead of?

[image: Git - SourceTree screenshot]

**UPDATE**

git status gives me:

```
JustMe@IMRAY ~/Projects/BlaBlaUser/gitPractice (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: What does `git status` on your local repo give you?

Comment: `

JustMe@IMRAY ~/Projects/BlaBlaUser/gitPractice (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Basically, you need to `push` to your remote branch again to get rid of the `2 ahead` so to speak.

The master (the one on the top) is your local tracking branch, and `origin/master` is a remote tracking branch that records the status of the remote repository from your last `push`, `pull`, or `fetch`. `origin` refers to your remote repository and `master` is the current branch (also default) for that repository.

So in essence, it says that your branch (`master`) is ahead of the remote master branch (`origin/master`) by two commits, and that is why I say that you need to `push` again.

When you do a `git status` on your local, it should give you more clue about what is to be done.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have local commits that have not yet been pushed to that remote.

For example:

```
* (master) Fix bar
* Fix foo
* (origin/master) Add bar
* Add foo
```

(newer commits are at the top)

Here you see that `origin/master` is two commits behind `master`.

You may use `git push origin master` to push your `master` branch to `origin`.

Comment: @Drew Noakes what I don't understand is why Imray need to push again after he has already done one push? He said "Then I pushed again. It worked." I thought this push would sync up the origin/master?

Comment: @CSnerd if the push succeeds then there's no need to push again. However if it fails, you have to fix the problem then push again.